Service Account Can't Generate Signed URL from Cloud Storage

Error: AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

I have a Cloud Run instance running a python application. The application calls on Cloud Storage to generate a signed URL:
@classmethod
    def view_documents(cls, email, filename) -> str | None:
        bucket = cls.client.bucket(cls.bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(f"{email}/{filename}")
        if blob.exists():
            url = blob.generate_signed_url(
                version="v4",
                response_disposition="inline",
                service_account_email="main-app@tapnfc-ef8ce.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                expiration=timedelta(minutes=15),
                method="GET",
            )
            return url
        return None

Cloud run supports attaching a service account (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#attached-sa).
In my cloud run main-app instance, I have attached the service account main-app@tapnfc-ef8ce.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

The service account main-app@tapnfc-ef8ce.iam.gserviceaccount.com has the following permissions:

If the cloud run instance utilizes main-app@tapnfc-ef8ce.iam.gserviceaccount.com, and the service account includes the Storage Object Viewer role, why can the cloud run instance not generate a signed url?
I want to avoid using a service account key, as they are less secure (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#service-accounts).
References I tried:

Generating Cloud Storage Signed URL from Google Cloud Function without using explicit key file
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/338
How to generate a Blob signed url in Google Cloud Run?


You are very close. In your case, you must explicitly provide the service account email in parameter. That's all.

@guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, but am getting the same error. In the function generate_signed_url, I added the parameter: service_account_email="main-app@tapnfc-ef8ce.iam.gserviceaccount.com". AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

I made the commit in the client libraries 3.5 years ago and I'm still surprise the signature or requirements didn't changes (I made the update quickly, I'm not a python developer, I was sure it will be improve during the years). Especially, providing the credentials token is pretty weird! https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/pull/356

I found the solution by guillaume's tip and revisiting the answer here (How to generate a Blob signed url in Google Cloud Run?). Below is the final code snippet:

Get the credentials from google.auth.default()
Refresh the credentials with credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
Put in the parameters service_account_email and access_token, both taken from credentials.

    @classmethod
    def view_documents(cls, email, filename) -> str | None:
        bucket = cls.client.bucket(cls.bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(f"{email}/{filename}")
        if blob.exists():
            credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
            credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
            # Ensure Cloud Run has the service account attached to it
            # Ensure that IAM Service Account Credentials API is enabled. 
            if hasattr(credentials, "service_account_email"):
                url = blob.generate_signed_url(
                    version="v4",
                    response_disposition="inline",
                    expiration=timedelta(minutes=15),
                    service_account_email=credentials.service_account_email,
                    access_token=credentials.token,
                    method="GET",
                )
                return url
        return None

